# why it not takes third value that b3.name = getchar();

Tags: gcc, struct

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct Books
{
    char name;
};
int main()
{
    struct Books b1;
    struct Books b2;
    struct Books b3;
    b1.name = getchar();
    printf("%c\n",b1.name);
    b2.name = getchar();
    printf("%c\n",b2.name);
    b3.name = getchar();
    printf("%c\n",b3.name);
    return 0;

 }
```

/* "why it not takes third value that is b3.name = getchar();
but it works fine with int and float."

ahindra@ahindra:~/Documents/c_c++$ gcc test.c -o test
ahindra@ahindra:~/Documents/c_c++$ ./test
f
f

j
j
ahindra@ahindra:~/Documents/c_c++$

*/

Comment: Could you include the output of this program including any errors that happen? Thanks!

Comment: ahindra@ahindra:~/Documents/c_c++$ gcc test.c -o test
ahindra@ahindra:~/Documents/c_c++$ ./test
f
f


j
j
ahindra@ahindra:~/Documents/c_c++$

Comment: the last lines looks confusing, I'd suggest to reformat your post, to make it more readable.